# How to generate an Australian ABN number?

Tags: business-intelligence

I need, for testing purposes, to generate some valid, random ABNs (Australian Business Numbers).

The following are some links I was able to find that discuss how to validate an ABN, but it's not really clear to me how to *generate* values.

[skorks.com/2011/08/even-boring-form-data-can-be-interesting-for-a-developer](http://skorks.com/2011/08/even-boring-form-data-can-be-interesting-for-a-developer)

[ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/13187.htm](http://ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/13187.htm)

[abr.business.gov.au](http://abr.business.gov.au)

[search.cpan.org/~adamk/Business-AU-ABN-1.09/lib/Business/AU/ABN.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Business-AU-ABN-1.09/lib/Business/AU/ABN.pm)

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: I think this question is pretty clear, at least it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing anything about it, you can just brute force it. This is fine if it's a one-time fixture generation. Not knowing if there is any convention for test numbers, you have to assume many of those generated are likely to represent real business entities.

```
use strictures;
use Business::AU::ABN "validate_abn";

my $desired = 10; # 1_000;
my $abn = 12_004_044_937; # Example from BAA Pod.
my @abn;
until ( not $desired )
{
    next unless my $valid = validate_abn( $abn++ );
    $desired--;
    push @abn, $valid;
}

print join($/, @abn), $/;

__END__
12 004 044 937
12 004 044 969
12 004 045 391
12 004 045 440
12 004 045 472
12 004 045 521
12 004 045 553
12 004 045 585
12 004 045 602
12 004 045 634
```

Comment: Approximately 88 out of 89 candidate numbers would be rejected... but that's probably fine if speed is not an issue.

Comment: Yes, speed is not a factor here.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it does not matter if yhey represent real entities as those numbers will not be used alone.

Answer (score 14):

From your link http://web.archive.org/web/20130405011257/http://www.ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/13187.htm, it seems to me you could:

1. Pick nine arbitrary (random) digits.

   For example, suppose we choose 004085616.
2. Put 10 in front of those digits (just temporarily).

   This gives us 10004085616.
3. Apply the weighting factor as described on http://web.archive.org/web/20130405011257/http://www.ato.gov.au/businesses/content.aspx?doc=/content/13187.htm.

   This gives us 402.
4. Calculate the remainder when you divide by 89.

   The remainder is 46.
5. Subtract that remainder from 89.

   The result is 43.
6. Add 10 to that result to get the new leftmost digits.

   Now we have 53. Insert that in front of 004085616 to get 53004085616.

Comment: Thanks, will upvote Ashley and you when I can.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Putting a '10' at the start makes the weighted value 412, according to my calculations. If you use '00', then everything works fine.

Comment: Thats my abn you insensitive clod... Not really mine.
http://abr.business.gov.au/SearchByAbn.aspx?abn=53004085616

Comment: Matthew, when applying the weighting rule you need to subtract 1 from the first digit, this means it would be '00'.

Comment: I've implemented this in PHP, tested and works. http://pastebin.com/zrmLHzWs

Comment: Somewhat related, I've made a snippet to generate a valid ACN as well: https://pastebin.com/q1cCuRVr

Comment: random numbers for the ACN part (last nine digits) won't work as 9 out of 10 will get rejected.  The ACN has an algorithm too, so you need to generate 8 digits, calculate the checksum as per https://asic.gov.au/for-business/registering-a-company/steps-to-register-a-company/australian-company-numbers/australian-company-number-digit-check/ and then run a similar algorithm to the above.

Comment: A Powershell version to generate ABN is here: https://pastebin.com/N0i89Pfv and ACN https://pastebin.com/c8Au2ATK

Comment: WTF, it actually works, omg ! @AdrianBrown I copied your PHP example and converted it to Javascript, and it worked.